# C# Assigning fields from unknown list length

Tags: c#, mysql, list, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game in Unity, that allows users to enter SQL commands.

Lets say I have a table called Terminals in my SQL database with the columns Id, Name, Type and Hacked.

If the user enters a SELECT command, e.g `SELECT Id, Name FROM Terminals;` then the lineList gets added the number of data fields that get returned, e.g. Id and Name only.

My question is, how do I assign the properties in the Terminals class to the correct values that get returned from the SQL query?

Here's my code:

```
public class SQLConnect : MonoBehaviour {
private void Query(string sqlCommand)
{
    using (dbCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (dbcmd = dbCon.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbcmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;
            dbCon.Open();

            using (reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var readList = new List<List<object>>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var lineList = new List<object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        lineList.Add(reader.GetValue(i)); // This reads the entries in a row
                    }

                    readList.Add(lineList);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public static class SQLDynamicData
{
    public static List<Terminals> TerminalList;

    public class Terminals
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool Hacked { get; set; }

        public Terminals(int id, string name, string type, bool hacked)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
            Hacked = hacked;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
using (reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var readList = new List<List<object>>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var lineList = new List<object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        lineList.Add(reader.GetValue(i)); // This reads the entries in a row
                    }
                 readList.Add(lineList);
                }
                foreach (var item in readList)
                {
                    SQLDynamicData.TerminalList.Add(new SQLDynamicData.Terminals(Convert.ToInt32(item[0]), item[1].ToString(), item[2].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(item[3])));
                }
            }
```

The problem with this is, that obviously if the data returned is just Id and Name, then item[2] and item[3] throw exceptions. Also, Name might be returned first and not Id if the user just selects Name and nothing else, in which case converting item[0] to an int isn't correct

How do I do this? I need to do this because I want to update my in game objects based on SQL data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which columns are present in the DataReader created by your query you could use the GetSchemaTable method that returns a table with the description of your columns. In this context you are interested only in the name of the columns, so you could create a simple `List<string>` with the names of your columns. 
This opens the way to use a `List<Terminals>` instead of that complex `List<List<object>>`

Of course, we need also a method to leave your Query method as generic as possible in such a way, that if you pass an incomplete query text for another class, it will be possible to use the same code.
A simple way to reach this goal is to separate the usual stuff that opens the connection, create the command, execute it and loops over the records from the task of reading the content of the reader. This could be achieved if you pass to your Query method an Action delegate that receives your DataReader and the List of columns present in the datareader.

So, your Query method changes to

```
private void Query(string sqlCommand, Action<SqlDataReader, List<string> loader)
{
    using (dbCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (dbcmd = dbCon.CreateCommand())
    {
        dbcmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;
        dbCon.Open();
        DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        List<string> columns = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("COLUMNNAME")).ToList();
        using (reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
              if(loader != null) 
                loader(reader, columns);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Query method doesn't know how to retrieve the fields from the query, but leaves this task to a special method received as its second parameter. This method wants two parameters, an DataReader and the List of the column names. With them it creates a Terminals instance, extracts the columns values (checking if the expected columns are present) and add the Terminals instance to the global list of Terminals.

Then, whoever calls the Query method should provide the method that effectively loads the data, a method like this

```
private void LoadTerminalsData(SqlDataReader reader, List<string> cols)
{
    Terminals t = new Terminals();
    if(cols.IndexOf("id") != -1)
        t.id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
    if(cols.IndexOf("Name") != -1)
        t.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
    if(cols.IndexOf("Type") != -1)
        t.Type = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Type"));
    if(cols.IndexOf("Hacked") != -1)
        t.Hacked = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Hacked"));
    listOfTerminals.Add(t);
}
```

Call everything passing to the Query method something like this

```
....Query("select id, Name from Terminals", LoadTerminalData);
```

Comment: That works great, thanks. How would I get the table name that is currently being operated on though?

dt.TableName gives me "SchemaTable", and not "Terminals".

Comment: I am not aware of any method to get this info directly from the DataReader. The connection object has a GetSchema("TABLES") that return all the tables present in your db but the one used by the DataReader is not identified in any particular way. However if your LoadTerminalsData is a method dedicated to the Terminals class (and table) while a different class will have its own method and its own table, so you are Always in a position to know your tablename. If you really need this name inside the Query method you could always add a third parameter with the table name.